# Difference between 事情 and 事件？

Tags: grammar, cantonese

What's the difference between 事情 and 事件? They both seem to be generic terms that refer to "event, thing, affair".

事件：http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4421/

事情：http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4090/

1) Are they interchangeable?

2) Is there a difference between Cantonese and Mandarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions of these two terms are quite different, clearly not interchangeable.

There is no difference between Cantonese and Mandarin for these terms

> 事件: event; occasion; happening

Example:

偷車**事件** (car stealing **occasion** )

天安門**事件** (Tiananmen Square **event/ incident**)

密室殺人**事件** (the **occasion/ happening** of murder in a locked room )

> 事情: matter; affair; thing; business

Example:

事情就是這樣 (the  **matters/ things** are like this)

沒你的事情 (there are no **business** of yours)

這**事情**我管不了 (I can't deal with this **affair**)

> 事件 is something already completed
>
> 事情 can be something already happened or something that's on going.

Example:

**事情**到了這個地步 (**things** have got to this point)

我也不知**事情**再發展下去會什樣 (I don't know what will happen as the **matter** continue to develope)

You cannot say **事件**到了這個地步 or **事件**再發展下去, because a 事件 is something that had been completed.

Comment: another awesome response. thanks! it sounds like the key is whether an event has completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, 事情 tends to be neutral; 事件 for nasty things (rather like "incident" in English).